# Mocking rest client class using mockito throw null pointer exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito, rest-client, springmockito

Hi i have class `RestClientUtil` which perform all the connection related operation with server and get the response using rest Services. When i tried to mock my restClientUtil its mocked successfully but when i tried calling method of this class,method will return response as null.when i see  restClientUtil variable in debug mode ,property of this class like `pbsOrderStatusUrl` `sellerCode` etc are coming null may be because of this reason response is coming null so please tell me the way to write mockito of my `OrderStatusUpdate` which is based upon response of RestClientUtil class

This is the method of RestClientUtilClass

```
 public class RestClientUtil{
       @Value("#{externalProperties['PBSUrl']}")
      private String pbsUrl;

    @Value("#{externalProperties['PBSOrderStatusUrl']}")
    private String pbsOrderStatusUrl;

    @Value("#{externalProperties['sellerCode']}")
    private String sellerCode;

    @Value("#{externalProperties['PAYMENT_CLIENT_URL']}")
    private String paymentClientURL;

    @Value("#{externalProperties['PBS_COMMUNICATION_URL']}")
    private String pbsCommunicationURL;

    private WebResource webResource;    

public com.mycompany.wrapper.orderstatusupdate.resp.Response orderStatusUpdateToProvider(
            com.mycompany.wrapper.orderstatusupdate.req.Request req, String specificURL)
            throws EcomGenericException {
        com.mycompany.wrapper.orderstatusupdate.resp.Response response = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < 3; i++) {
//pbsUrl is some UrlTo differntServer
            try {
                Client client = Client.create();
                WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
                        pbsUrl).build());
                log.debug("Input to the PBS system for orderStatusUpdateToProvider ==> "
                        + req);
                MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
                queryParams.add("sellerCode", sellerCode);
                response = webResource.path("seller").path("orders")
                        .path(specificURL).queryParams(queryParams)
                        .header("correlationId", req.getCorrelationId())
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                        .post(com.mycompany.wrapper.orderstatusupdate.resp.Response.class,
                                req);
                log.trace("response ==> " + response);
                if (null == response) {
                    log.error("Order Update Status  is null");
                    throw new EcomGenericException("validation_500");
                }
                break;
            } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {

            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

This is the class where i am calling RestClientUtil Method

```
     @Service
    public class OrderStatusUpdate {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger
                .getLogger(OrderStatusUpdate.class);
        @Resource(name = "restClientUtil")
        protected RestClientUtil restClientUtil;

        @Resource(name = "blOrderService")
        protected OrderService orderService;
        public void setRestClientUtil(RestClientUtil restClientUtil) {
            this.restClientUtil = restClientUtil;
        }

        public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
            this.orderService = orderService;
        }


        public void orderStatusUpdate(Order order, String providerStatus, String targetStatus,
                String dateTime, String targetURI) throws EcomGenericException,  org.broadleafcommerce.core.pricing.service.exception.PricingException {

            Request request = new ObjectFactory()
                    .createRequest();
            Request.Order orderReq = new Request.Order();
            orderReq.setOrderId(order.getOrderNumber());
            orderReq.setStatus(providerStatus);
            orderReq.setDateTime(dateTime);
            request.setOrder(orderReq);
            request.setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            com.mycompany.wrapper.orderstatusupdate.resp.Response response = restClientUtil.orderStatusUpdateToProvider(request,targetURI);
            if (response != null && ApplicationConstants.PROVIDER_SUCCESS_IDENTIFIER.equals(response.getStatus().getCode())) {
                order.setStatus(CustomOrderStatus.getInstance(targetStatus));
                orderService.save(order, false);
            } else {
logger.error("OrderStatusUpdate call failed from the Provider end for ECOM OrderID " +order.getId()+ " with ErrorCode "+ response.getStatus().getCode() + " with Error message "+ response.getStatus().getMessage());
            throw new EcomGenericException("validation_500");
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the mockito Test i tried to implement

```
  public class OrderStatusUpdateTest {

    protected RestClientUtil restClientUtil;

    protected OrderService orderService;

    protected OrderStatusUpdate orderStatusUpdate;
    protected Request request;
    private Response response;
    private Order blcOrder;
    private com.mycompany.account.CustomOrderStatus CustomOrderStatus;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
     restClientUtil=mock(RestClientUtil.class);
     orderService=mock(OrderService.class);
     blcOrder=new OrderImpl();
     request=new Request();
     blcOrder.setStatus(CustomOrderStatus.PAYMENT_COMPLETED);
     orderStatusUpdate=new OrderStatusUpdate();
     orderStatusUpdate.setOrderService(orderService);
     orderStatusUpdate.setRestClientUtil(restClientUtil);
     Request.Order order=new Request.Order();
     order.setOrderId("123455");
     order.setStatus("PAYMENT COMPLETED");
     order.setDateTime("2013-11-21T09:30:47+0500");
     request.setCorrelationId("12343");
     request.setOrder(order);

     when(restClientUtil.orderStatusUpdateToProvider(request, "http://localhost:8080/")).thenReturn(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws PricingException {

        orderStatusUpdate.orderStatusUpdate(blcOrder, "PAYMENT COMPLETED","IN_PAYMENT", "2013-11-21T09:30:47+0500", "http://localhost:8080/");
        verify(restClientUtil.orderStatusUpdateToProvider(request, "http://localhost:8080/"));
        verify(orderService.save(blcOrder, false));

        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

this is the  error log

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.api.service.orderstatusupdate.OrderStatusUpdate.orderStatusUpdate(OrderStatusUpdate.java:72)
    at com.mycompany.api.service.orderstatusupdate.test.OrderStatusUpdateTest.test(OrderStatusUpdateTest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you highlight line 72 in your `OrderStatusUpdate` class with `// exception here` or similar.

Comment: @Duncan u can see the logger inside the OrderStatusUpdate class method orderStatusUpdate(....) this is 72 line cause here response is used

Comment: @Duncan FYI class level variable is used in RestCLientUtil class is populated through property file in real time

Comment: `response` is not initialized in the test case and is being returned when orderStatusUpdateToProvider is called. In the logger , you are trying to read the status code from a null object.

Comment: @Duncan i can remove the logger no problem but i need response why its coming null can u help me on this

Comment: @r3ap3r i can remove the logger but i still need response object for testing my functionality

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
when(restClientUtil.orderStatusUpdateToProvider(request,"http://localhost:8080")).thenReturn(response);
```

`response` is not initialized.

The `if-else` condition is incorrect in `orderStatusUpdate` method, because if the `response` is **null**, the logger still tries to access the status code from it.

Comment: i will remove the logger but still response is coming null i need response for testing my function functionality how do i get that ?

Comment: @henrycharles In your test, you need to construct your `response` object. I.e. `response = new Response();`, or similar.

Comment: @Duncan i will create response object no problem, but in my restClientUtil class it will go to orderStatusUpdateToProvider method here i am having problem cause this need pbsURL sellerCode and many more parameter, then call the post method for getting the response.In real time i am hitting different service for getting response which is avaiblable in different machine they are expecting such huge list of parameter in webResource then they are sending the response now question is how i mock this behaviour to get response in my OrderStatusUpdate class